# get mean value from X measurements

Tags: c, esp8266

I am trying to program an Mikrocontroller to automatically measure a distance via ultrasonic sensor and upload the value to thingSpeak. Since the sensor is not very reliable I'm trying to take multiple measurements and upload the mean value.
I am using the `#include <NewPing.h>` Library so `sonar.ping_cm()`gives me the distance.
My Code looks like this:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <NewPing.h>
void loop() {
float distance_1 = sonar.ping_cm();
delay(50);
float distance_2 = sonar.ping_cm();
delay(50);
float distance_3 = sonar.ping_cm();
mean distance = (distance_1+distance_2+distance_3)/3
upload  to thingSpeak
```

what is a good approach to extend this method to X measurements without writing X lines?

Comment: Is X a constant value?

Comment: @ThunderStorm Doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` is parameter how many measurements must be created before average calculation.

```
float getAverage(int X) {
    float out = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        out += sonar.ping_cm();
    }
    return out / (float)X;
}
```

Comment: why not `for (i = 0; i<=X;i++)` ?

Comment: If you put x to 1, then you want 1 measurement. With your option you would have 2.

Answer (score 1):

for loop look ok:

```
void loop(const int x) {
    float distance_1 = 0.0;
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        distance_1 += sonar.ping_cm();
        delay(50);
    }
    mean distance = (distance_1)/x;
```

Comment: `(x+1);`? Are you sure?